# Display Woocommerce Metadata value on Frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I installed a plugin that displays the metadata of every post (normal posts and products) I would like to be able to display the value of a metadata on the frontend - I am designing a single post (single product) page - and there's a specific metadata field that I would like to display on that page. Any Guidance please?
here's a screenshot of the metadata fields that I have:
[Metadata fields in the dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weqPj.png)

if you can guide me to display any metadata value, I will be able to do it and choose the desired fields that I want to display on the frontend.

I appreciate your help so much!

I tried different plugins, couldn't find a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do the following in the file single.php or single-product.php:

```
    $value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "key", true );
    echo "<p>$value</p>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me a very useful answer!

I replaced echo with print_r - now it returns the following
Array ( [1] => Array ( [ticket] => 31 [prize] => £35 ) [2] => Array ( [ticket] => 74 [prize] => £35 ) [3] => Array ( [ticket] => 88 [prize] => £35 ) )

do you have any idea how to only show the values without the array word and the arrows?

Comment: You have to use the loop: foreach($value as $item){ echo $item['ticket'] . $item['prize]}